# laravel get eloquent data using its relations Ids

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three main **mySQL** tables:

- users
- tags
- news_articles

I also have many to many tables to connect them as needed.

I want to grab all the articles that share the same tags as users so I can personalise their experience.

(example): say a user has tags for "Trump" or "Brexit" I want to grab all the news articles that also have Trump or Brexit.

I could grab the whole data pool and make calculations but that might get unnecessarily server intensive so is there a way of doing it through Eloquent?

**Also** is Eloquent capable of tallying the user tags to determine which tags the user is most interested in before grabbing the articles or would that need a workaround after?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? This question is way too vague and is just asking for the code which you can find in the documentation. The second part can be done by adding a read_count on news-articles for example.

Comment: Hey Christoph, thank you for your response, I made sure to scour the internet before posting this question and couldn't find the answer to this in the Eloquent documentation, perhaps I missed something, would you be able to give me a link? I've tried queries within functions within "where()"s and "filter()" But to my knowledge Eloquents QueryBuilder only addresses one table at a time, I think my answer lies elsewhere, I'm just looking for the right tree to bark up.

Comment: First you should define relationships https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships. on that relationships you can add where() etc.

$user->tags()->where('name', 'TRUMP')->firstOrFail();  will give you all tags with trump for a users for example.

Answer (score 0):

Christophvh's response did work for me in the end. After some more time with Eloquent I found plenty more ways of doing this.

A way I would go about this now for anyone who happens to be stuck:

By creating a `tags` method in my `User` and `Article` models to return all related tags I can then do the following.

```
$userTags = $user->tags()->pluck('name')->get()->toArray();

$articles = Article::whereHas('tags', function($tag) use ($userTags) {
    $tag->where('name', $userTags)->get();
})->get();
```

The above code should:

- Get only the name field of all tags belonging to a user and store them in an array.
- Grab all articles where their related tags name field contain any tag in the $userTags variable

To create a priority tags list I would just need to run `array_count_values($userTags)` and order it by the returned values, then pass the new ordered `$userTags` array into the Eloquent query.